# MediaWiki sends wrong header expires

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mediawiki, expires-header

I have Debian, Apache, MediaWiki. I set Expires in .htaccess for plus one month. 
MediaWiki sends header 
**Expires**: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
But if I create any simple script or file, it shows the correct information. Anyone else encountered this? I noticed this on many MediaWiki sites.
Thank you.

I use this .htaccess: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MaxKorz/htaccess/master/.htaccess
but edit expires for plus one month.

Comment: Please describe this in more detail. Provide link to your installation, settings, .htaccess file.

Comment: I use this .htaccess:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MaxKorz/htaccess/master/.htaccess but edit expires for plus one month.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manage MediaWiki's caching behavior with external tools. Expires: set to 1970 is normal for MW without a HTTP cache in front of it (and even with a cache it will be set to expire immediately, but with a s-maxage). If you're worried that clients will be requesting stuff repeatedly - there's no problem here because If-Modified-Since will be used to avoid unneeded transfers. Without this, there will be problems with letting clients know when a page has changed.